# MQL4 How to disable compiler warnings

Tags: mql4

I am looking for preprocessor directive to disable compiler warnings for desired block of code in MQL4.

I have some bitwise IFs and don't want to cast everything explicitly like:

```
if ( (bool)(flag & 0x00110101) ) {}
```

Instead I am looking for something like:

```
#nowarn
if ( flag & 0x00110101 ) {}
```

Comment: check if your code has `#property strict` in any of the files that compile

Comment: Yes it does, but its irrelevant because it throws warnings with and without Strict. Anyway I already did it with macro #define IF(x)  if((x) != 0)